# R data.table conditional aggregation

Tags: r, data.table

I'm faced with (what I think) is a tough problem with aggregations on `data.table`
I've the following  `data.table`

```
structure(list(id1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), id2 = c("x", 
"y", "z", "x", "u", "y", "z"), val = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3)), .Names = c("id1", 
"id2", "val"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1f66a78>)
```

I would like to create conditional aggregates on the `val` column for this data based on the second column `id2`. The way the aggregation is done is to only include `id1` groups which have at least one element from a given `id2` element. I'll step through an example to show what I mean.

The conditional aggregate for `x` (the first row 2nd column) would include `val` values 2,1,2 for `id1 = a` and `val` values  = 1,3 from `id1 = b`  because `id2=x` exists for them but no values from `id1=c`, resulting in a value of 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 3 = 9. I want the 9 as a 4th column in every row where `id2 = x` appears.

Likewise, I want to do this for all `id2` values. So the final output would be

```
    id1 id2 val c.sum
1:   a   x   2     9
2:   a   y   1    12
3:   a   z   2    12
4:   b   x   1     9
5:   b   u   3     4
6:   c   y   4    12
7:   c   z   3    14
```

Is this possible in R, data.table? Or any other package/method?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that `d` is your input structure:

```
library(data.table)

d[,c.sum:=sum(d$val[d$id1 %in% id1]),by=id2][]
```

How it works: `by=id2` groups input data table `d` by `id2`; `d$id1 %in% id1` selects rows in `d` whose `id1` matches `id1` of the group under consideration; `sum(d$val[...])` takes sum of values from such rows; finally, `c.sum:=sum(...)` adds a column `c.sum` to `d`. The ending `[]` are needed only for the printing purpose.

The output is:

```
#    id1 id2 val c.sum
# 1:   a   x   2     9
# 2:   a   y   1    12
# 3:   a   z   2    12
# 4:   b   x   1     9
# 5:   b   u   3     4
# 6:   c   y   4    12
# 7:   c   z   3    12
```

Comment: I get all values of 16.

Comment: @BondedDust: could it be related to the `data.table` version? I use data.table_1.9.4.

Comment: This must require loading a package.  I loaded `data.table`, but the above line doesn't work for me.  can you please add any `library()` statements that are required for this solution to run?

Comment: Don't know why you have the `[]` at the end. That isn't needed except for printing purposes.

Comment: @thelatemail, I had exactly printing purpose in mind )

Comment: I'd remove it - it isn't part of the code to actually assign the variable and could confuse people. I'd hate to see people learning to include `[]` needlessly after data.table code just because.

Comment: I get an error stating 'unused argument (by = id2)'

Comment: @Jthorpe, Before running this line, you need to load the `data.table`  package (sorry for not mentioning that in the original version of the answer--I didn't do that because the question was specifically related to `data.table`), and to load the input structure from the question (e.g. `d <- structure(list(id1 = ...`.

Comment: @thelatemail If one is not familiar with data.table yet, he/she may get confused; seeing no outcome in R Console made me confused before. It would be good to add a note so that users know `[]` is necessary just for printing purposes.

Comment: @jazzurro - then just add `d` or `print(d)` as a final line in the answer. It's just bizarre to have `[]` tacked on the end when it functionally does nothing. I know `data.table` and it threw me for a second.

Comment: @thelatemail I understand your point. I also think in your way. Now the OP added a note. So users will know `[]` is just for printing. I hope this `[]` will change in the future.

Comment: Still works for me. Do you try it for a sample data set?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit brute force, but it should work (assuming `data` is your data structure):

```
id1_sums <- tapply(data$val,data$id1,sum)  
for(id in unique(data$id2))
    data$c.sum[data$id2  == id] <- sum(
            id1_sums[which(names(id1_sums) %in% data$id1[data$id2 == id])])
```