# Summing across rows of a data.table for specific columns with NA

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
TEST <- data.table(Time=c("0","0","0","7","7","7","12"),
             Zone=c("1","1","0","1","0","0","1"),
             quadrat=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1),
             Sp1=c(NA,4,29,9,1,2,10),
             Sp2=c(NA,NA,11,15,32,15,10),
             Sp3=c(NA,0,1,1,1,1,0))

TEST[, SumAbundance := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = 4:6]
```

If there are three NA then I think that SumAbundance should be `NA`. If there is 1 or 2 `NA` values then still compute the sum and ignore the `NA`.

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this would be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955491/r-data-table-conditional-aggregation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can have several options for this i.e. either do the `rowSums` first and then `replace` the rows where all are `NA` or create an index in `i` to do the sum only for those rows with at least one non-NA.

```
library(data.table)
TEST[, SumAbundance := replace(rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE),
           Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na)), NA), .SDcols = 4:6]
```

---

Or slightly more compact option

```
TEST[, SumAbundance :=  (NA^!rowSums(!is.na(.SD))) * 
             rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = 4:6]
```

---

Or construct a function and reuse

```
rowSums_new <- function(dat) {
  fifelse(rowSums(is.na(dat)) != ncol(dat), rowSums(dat, na.rm = TRUE),  NA_real_)
    }
TEST[, SumAbundance := rowSums_new(.SD), .SDcols = 4:6]
```

Comment: thanks so much can you show the 1 liner to replace the value if all 3 are NA?

Comment: @bvowe I updated with two options.  The second is slightly more compact than the first

Comment: I like the use of the function so that the ```.SDcols``` does not need to be referred to twice.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to subset in `i` and then update in `j`:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Time=c("0","0","0","7","7","7","12"),
                   Zone=c("1","1","0","1","0","0","1"),
                   quadrat=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1),
                   Sp1=c(NA,4,29,9,1,2,10),
                   Sp2=c(NA,NA,11,15,32,15,10),
                   Sp3=c(NA,0,1,1,1,1,0))

dt[!(is.na(Sp1) & is.na(Sp2) &is.na(Sp3)),
     SumAbundance := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE),
     .SDcols = 4:6]

dt
#>    Time Zone quadrat Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 SumAbundance
#> 1:    0    1       1  NA  NA  NA           NA
#> 2:    0    1       2   4  NA   0            4
#> 3:    0    0       3  29  11   1           41
#> 4:    7    1       1   9  15   1           25
#> 5:    7    0       2   1  32   1           34
#> 6:    7    0       3   2  15   1           18
#> 7:   12    1       1  10  10   0           20
```

@Akrun was using `Reduce` to reduce the amount of typing. We could have used that approach in this `i` statement as well.

Comment: Perhaps, scalable ? `cols <- 4:6;TEST[rowSums(!is.na(TEST[, ..cols])) != 0, SumAbundance := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = cols]`